# Is it possible to turn a ca-full instance of FreeIPA 4.3 to a ca-less one?

Tags: certificate-authority, freeipa

I have a ca-full installation of FreeIPA 4.3, but I would like to turn it into a [ca-less](https://www.freeipa.org/page/V3/CA-less_install) one. The installation doesn't have any replica, it is only one host.

What would be the best path to achieve that?

Comment: You want to run the whole domain without a CA? You can't do that.

Comment: The ca-less installation does not mean without any CA, it means that FreeIPA does not managed anything CA related for you :) Please see [V3/CA-less install](https://www.freeipa.org/page/V3/CA-less_install) as a reference for this feature.